# How to implement tree made from possible moves in game Othello (Reversi)

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, tree, othello

I need help with making tree from possible moves in game Othello, on which I will later use MiniMax algorithm. Game is played in Player vs AI mode and I am always "1" on board and AI is always "2" on board. This is how my current function for getting best move for AI looks like:

```
def findMoveForAI(board, player, depth, start):
    best_score_for_move = -float('inf')
    play_x = play_y = -1
    moves = validMoves(board, player)
    if not moves:
        return (play_x , play_y)
    for x, y in moves:
        # this is where I would like to make tree
        (temp, total_fillped) = PlayMove(copy.deepcopy(board), x, y, player)
        move_eval = AlphaBeta(temp, player, depth, -999999999999, 999999999999, True, start)
        if move_eval > best_score_for_move  :
            best_score_for_move = move_eval 
            play_x = x; play_y= y
    return (play_x , play_y)
```

So, my idea is that on marked place, I make tree for every possible move for AI in that moment and then do MiniMax on it and get the best possible move. Problem is, that I don't know how to make tree. I have `class TreeNode` and `class Tree` but apparently, I don't know how to use them. This is how those 2 classes look like.

```
class TreeNode(object):

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.parent = None
        self.children = []
        self.data = data

    def is_root(self):
        return self.parent is None

    def is_leaf(self):
        return len(self.children) == 0

    def add_child(self, x):
        x.parent = self
        self.children.append(x)
```

```
class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
```

Also, this is how I initialize board if that's needed.

```
board = [['.' for x in range(8)] for y in range(8)]
```

I would really appreciate any kind of help because I feel like it should be done with recursion but it's really not my strongest side.

This is what I tried:

```
def makeTree(tree, board, player, depth):
    if depth > 0:
        new_player = change_player(player)
        possible_moves = validMoves(board, new_player)
        for x, y in possible_moves:
            new_board = PlayMove(copy.deepcopy(board), x, y, new_player)[0]
            child_tree = makeTree(tree, new_board, new_player, depth - 1)
            tree.add_child(child_tree)
    return tree
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Asking for "any kind of help" is too broad. Please focus on a specific issue.

Comment: Well, I think steps I should take are:
1. Play move
2. Store board in node
3. Get all possible moves for opponent
4. For every opponent move I play it and then add it as child to previous node
Problem is, I don't know how to implement recursion to connect all those moves.

Comment: But the alphabeta algorithm is well documented on the internet (with recursion)? Did you check?

Comment: I know how to implement alphabeta on tree but I need to make the tree first. That is the problem.

Comment: There is no tree needed to perform alphabeta. The idea is that you just make the moves as you execute the minimax/alphabeta algorithm, recurse, evaluate and return. This represents itself a recursion tree, but the tree is never really persisted.

Comment: I know that I don't need to make Tree structure, but it is a must since it is requirement of my project. All I need to do, is make Tree structure from possible moves and then do minimax on that tree. That is requirement from my project.

Comment: What is `ukupno` in your code? You never use it... What does `promeniIgraca` do?

Comment: ```ukupno``` means total_pieces_flipped, it's changed now in post. I don't use it anywhere cause it's not needed. ```promeniIgraca``` is change_player. Changed it also.

Comment: What do you need the data of your nodes to be? The board? Will you store the player, the move, ... in the tree?

Comment: Main thing is that I have Heuristic evaluation of board in the leaves since that is what I need to get up the tree with minimax. So I am not sure how to do it. I would like to avoid unnecessary storing data.

Comment: So you don't need the x, y, or player in the tree? Where is the heuristic calculation in your code?

Comment: I will just assume that you need this info. At least you need to get the best *move*, so the tree should have `x` and `y` somewhere. I will assume you have a `heuristic(board, player)` function. Posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need your recursive function to return a `TreeNode` instance, not a `Tree` instance. The top level call will then return the root node, which should then be assigned to the `root` attribute of a single `Tree` instance.

I would also suggest creating an `Edge` class, so you can store the information about the move that was played in the parent board in order to get to the child board.

If I understand correctly you want to separate the minimax/alphabeta algorithm from the actual game rules, and first create the tree of states (specific to the game), and then feed that to a generic minimax/alphabeta algorithm which can then be ignorant about the game rules, and just focus on the information in the tree.

Here is an idea for an implementation:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

class TreeNode:

    def __init__(self, board, player, value=None):
        self.parent = None
        self.children = []
        self.board = board
        self.player = player
        self.value = value  # Initially only provided for leaf nodes

    def is_root(self):
        return self.parent is None

    def is_leaf(self):
        return len(self.children) == 0

    def add_edge(self, edge):
        edge.child.parent = self
        self.children.append(edge)

    def to_list(self):  # to ease debugging...
        return [self.board, [edge.child.to_list() for edge in self.children]]

class Edge:
    def __init__(self, x, y, child):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.child = child

    
def makeTree(board, player, depth):

    def makeNode(board, player, depth):
        if depth == 0:  # Create a leaf with a heuristic value
            return TreeNode(board, player, heuristic(board, player))
        
        node = TreeNode(board, player)
        new_player = change_player(player)
        possible_moves = validMoves(board, new_player)
        for x, y in possible_moves:
            new_board = PlayMove(copy.deepcopy(board), x, y, new_player)[0]
            node.add_edge(Edge(x, y, makeNode(new_board, new_player, depth - 1)))
        return node

    tree = Tree()
    tree.root = makeNode(board, player, depth)
    return tree
```

Your `findMoveForAI` and `AlphaBeta` functions would no longer get a `board` and `player` as argument, nor would they call `PlayMove`. Instead they would just traverse the tree. `findMoveForAI` would get the tree instance as argument, and `AlphaBeta` would get a node as argument. The values would bubble up the tree as this executes, based on the values that are stored in the leaves of the tree.

So `findMoveForAI` could look like this:

```
def findMoveForAI(tree):
    best_score_for_move = -float('inf')
    play_x = play_y = -1
    for x, y, child in tree.root.children:
        move_eval = AlphaBeta(child, depth, -999999999999, 999999999999)
        if move_eval > best_score_for_move:
            best_score_for_move = move_eval 
            play_x = x
            play_y = y
    return (play_x , play_y)
```

And the driver code would have these two steps:

```
DEPTH = 3
# ...
tree = makeTree(board, player, DEPTH) 
best_move = findMoveForAI(tree)
# ...
```